# Approximate area of overlap of rotated rectangles

Tags: algorithm, geometry, rectangles, clipping

I need to estimate the overlap ratio of two rectangles of arbitrary size and orientation.

I know how to perform the exact computation, using the Sutherland-Hodgman algorithm, which can be optimized for this case.

Anyway as I need to use that function intensively and perfect accuracy isn't required (say 10% error can be tolerated), I was wondering if it cannot be evaluated in a faster way, preferably branchless.

If that helps, one can assume the same aspect ratio for both rectangles, and ratio of the areas not exceeding 4.

---

**Update**:

1. For unrotated rectangles, the formula is

   (min(W0,DX+W1) - max(-W0,DX-W1)).(min(H0,DY+H1) - max(H0,DY-H1))

   or zero if any of the two factors is negative, where `DX`, `DY` are the differences between center coordinates, `W` and `H` denote the respective half sizes.
2. It is probably worthwhile to look at the curve of the common area for given placement of the centers and given sizes, when you vary the relative rotation angle.

Comment: Just a speculation, how about sampling? That is if the transform A maps a axis aligned, 0 centred rectangle to one of you rectangles, and B maps to the other then for a collection of sample points p from the second axis aligned rectangle you count the number of times inv(A)(B(p)) is in the first axis aligned rectangle; the ratio of the number of hits to the number of samples would be an approximation to the ratio of the area of intersection to the area of the second axis aligned rectangle.

Comment: @dmuir: that's quite right. Now the goal is to lessen the computational cost, so that the number of allowed samples would be very limited (like less than ten I guess).

Comment: if your language allows it you could do a lot of the sampling calculations in parallel

Comment: @dmuir: yep, vectorization is probably possible as the computation is quite regular.  Multithreading or GPU is unthinkable, due to the very fine grain.

Answer (score 0):

Sutherland-Hodgman algorithm is intended for intersection of convex clip polygon with arbitrary one. I would expect that algorithm especially designed for convex-convex case is faster.

I had good practical experience with O'Rourke algorithm (O(m+n)) for alike problem
*(area of intersections between two sets of thousands of rotated rectangles)*.

[Code link is here](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/compgeom.html) - convconv. AFAIR, some simplifications were possible for rectangles.

[Another algorithm](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~plante/compGeom/algorithm.html)

I doubt that any approximation approach could find a result significantly faster and with controlled accuracy.

Comment: Mh, here m=n=4 so that well optimized brute force is probably best, compared to sophisticated algorithms that suffer from a higher number of tests and branches. (For the exact approach I would use recursive S-H with four stages, making the clipping rectangle axis-parallel and hard-coding the side equations.) I am more looking for a single closed formula obtained for example by switching to other shapes (ellipses ?).

Comment: Yes, I thought you wanted for circles or ellipses, but couldn't imagine good approximation without determination of intersection region vertices or at least intersection type(corner-corner, corner-edge, cross, two corners inside and so on)